why we import reduce() function in python?
Basically in python we use map(), filter and reduce function. But we only import reduce function, not map or filter. why is it so??
I was learning and practicing , but I got stuck on this logic. please sort out my query..

Because the reduce function isn't part of Python's core but in an extra module functools.
